# What do ^ and $ mean in a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, dollar-sign

What is the difference between `"\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+"` and `"^\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+$"`? I have tried to google for it but no luck.

Comment: did you try your strings and regex with https://regex101.com/?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`^` means "Match the start of the string" (more exactly, the *position*  before the first character in the string, so it does not match an actual character).

`$` means "Match the end of the string" (the position after the last character in the string).

Both are called [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and ensure that the entire string is matched instead of just a substring.

So in your example, the first regex will report a match on `email@address.com.uk`, but the matched text will be `email@address.com`, probably not what you expected. The second regex will simply fail.

Be careful, as some regex implementations implicitly anchor the regex at the start/end of the string (for example Java's `.matches()`, if you're using that).

If the multiline option is set (using the `(?m)` flag, for example, or by doing `Pattern.compile("^\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+$", Pattern.MULTILINE)`), then `^` and `$` also match at the start and end of a *line*.

Comment: So if I Understand correctly then the string "email@address.com.uk" is perfectly matched with "\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+" but not "^\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+$"? but I have tested in java and the string failed with both cases. I still do not see the clear difference. Can you show the points based on my case?

Comment: Your regex only allows for one dot after the @ sign. Try `^[\\w.]+@[\\w.]+\\.\\w+$`. It's still not perfect (no regex will ever be for matching an e-mail address), but it's a bit more forgiving.

Comment: yes, according to your answer, the string "email@address.com.uk" would be matched with "\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+", but not with "^\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+$". This code: String s = "email@address.com.uk";
        System.out.println(s.matches("\\w+@\\w+[.]\\w+")); => false

Comment: Did you read my answer thoroughly? Java's `.matches()` adds anchors to your regex implicitly!

Answer (score 1):

Try the Javadoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

`^` and `$` match the beginnings/endings of a line (without consuming them)