# Unexpected result using ^ and $ in PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do ^ and $ mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908725/what-do-and-mean-in-a-regular-expression)

I'm not good at all at regular expression, i know they are so much important but never found the time to study them. Anyway i'm just tring to ensure that, among these strings:

```
MAX_AGE_60
MAX_AGE_80
...
MAX_AGE_X
```

where more in general `X` is a `integer`, **at least one match is found** and get the number `X`. So following the example on PHP documentation i wrote this:

```
// Starts and ends with the literal 'MAX_AGE_' followed by a group that is a 
// number with at least one digit. Case insensitive
$pattern = '/^MAX_AGE_(?P<max>\d+)$/i';

$test    = 'MAX_AGE_80';
$matches = array();

preg_match($pattern, $test, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The result is wrong (suprise...):

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Removing start/end delimiters (`^` and `$`) i get the correct result:

```
array (size=3)
  0     => string 'MAX_AGE_80' (length=10)
  'max' => string '80' (length=2)
  1     => string '80' (length=2)
```

So why i can't force that the string must start and end with that pattern? And how should interpret the result array? I mean indexes `0`, `1` and `max`?

Comment: In your specific case `^` and `$` could stay in the regex, if you also used the `/m` modifier to make both multi-line aware.

Comment: I get the expected result with/without `^` and `$`. Where is the problem?

Comment: @SalmanA does not work with the first (using `^` and `$`), removing them it works. Why?

Comment: ^ and $ are telling the regex that ^ is the line start and $ is the line end. If you want to use word boundaries use \b(regex)\b instead.

Comment: You example code seems to work as-is: http://ideone.com/ttA8X

Comment: You're making us guess your actual input string. Unclear if it's in fact a multi-line input text, or if there are just trailing newlines. Anyway, that's your answer.

Comment: umm...I don't see this as dublicate... 1. the question is not, what `^`and `$`'s function is, but why they don't work as intended. 2. the question about the output of the named subpattern has not been answered (short answer: index 0 is the whole matched string, all other numeric indices are matches to subpatterns, additional preg_match gives you the matches to named pattern with the name as index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing between the parentheses there. Try this:

```
$pattern = '/^MAX_AGE_[\p{N}]+$/iu';
```

And the difference between ^$ and not, is that they flag only matches that are at the beginning and/or the end of the LINE

You can use this site to test your expressions (non unicode):
http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Sorry i had not read your question well. Try this:
`$pattern = '/MAX_AGE_([\p{N}]+)?/ium';`

and use `preg_match_all` (it returns an array, look this up in php documentation online)

Comment: I'm sure that my test string will always contain at maximum 1 match, so why should i use preg_match_all?

Comment: Oh, sorry that wasn't very clear. If you are certain there will be only 1 match then you dont need to use preg_match_all. I thought you wanted to capture at least 1 match.

About your question, your string is not only one line. Regexp engine will search the entire block of text u give it, and so the pattern (designed for a line) will not match against several lines.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$pattern = '/^MAX_AGE_(?P<max>\d+)\s*$/i';
```

as there might be whitespace before the line ends.