# How Django resolve this non-greedy regex url pattern?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm following a tutorial which works with Django, there is a URL pattern like this:

```
url(r'^lists/(.+)/$', views.list_view, name='list_view')
```

That's a greedy regex pattern and it will match something such as: **lists/123/add_item/** with **123/add_item** as matched-group. That is not what is expected. So I tried to change it to non-greedy one like this:

```
url(r'^lists/(.+?)/$', views.list_view, name='list_view')
```

But Django still resolve it to views.list_view

Could you please give me some explanation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do ^ and $ mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908725/what-do-and-mean-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the trailing `$` from your regex, since that will always match the final `/` instead of the next.

I think the fact that Django does match the 2nd URL is due to Django not matching the URL but instead using a `re.search`. You can see this behaviour here: [Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/resolvers.py#L186)

Comment: Your answer seems explained regex part. but Django still resolve `lists/123/add_item` to `views.list_view`

Comment: I also guess that @daniel's answer is strictly the more correct one. Although  I'd highly recommend browsing the django source to understand more of what happens on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of `^lists/(.+?)/$`:

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `lists` matches the characters lists literally (case sensitive)
- `/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
- 1st Capturing Group `(.+?)`

  - `.+?` matches any character *(except for line terminators)*
  - `+?` Quantifier — Matches between **one** and **unlimited** times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
- `$` means end of string

*Credits: http://regex101.com*

But I didn't understand what you *want* exactly to match your pattern

*UPDATE*:

**Helpful link**: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

Comment: Hi! with that pattern, I was expecting it will match only: lists/123/ but not lists/123/add_item/

Comment: If you want to match a number only (probably an `id`), you can use `^lists/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$`

Comment: Yeah, agreed. that's somehow same solution from author of tutorial: ^lists/(\d+)/$. But I just wonder about my try.

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict your pattern to capture only what you want. In your case, it seems to be digits, so:

```
url(r'^lists/(\d+)/$', views.list_view, name='list_view')
```

Comment: I wonder about my try because if my URL is `lists/<username>/` instead of `lists/<id>/` then solutions like yours will not work.

Comment: Yes but then you need a different pattern, just as you will need different logic in the view. You should make your patterns as specific as possible.

Comment: In any case, if you wanted to capture all alphanumeric characters, you would just use `\w+`.

Comment: let's say: what should be pattern if I want different views for `lists/username/` and `lists/username/add_item`?

Comment: That is exactly what I just said. `r'^lists/(\w+)/$` and `r'^lists/(\w+)/add_item$`.