# Finding a pattern while being surrounded by other text in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a regex that finds a certain pattern. This works when the text is isolated. However I want this to work while it's being surrounded by other text and somehow extract it from there. Here's the pattern that I came up with. An example would be if 9708/32/M/J/15 is the text, it would find it. But if it's awfawf9708/32/M/J/15awfafwaf it can't find it.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\w/\\w/\\d{2}$");
```

How do I modify this to make it work in both scenarios?

Comment: You could omit the anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: Does not work. Same result

Comment: Did you try it like this? https://ideone.com/pXAkIE

Comment: You are probably using `Matcher.matches()`, which tries to match the entire String. You can match the partial text if you use `Matcher.find()`.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/XocQe0/1) works for me: `\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\w\/\w\/\d{2}`. I'm no `RegEx` nor `Java` expert, but by my understanding you reversed the escaping of the forward slash. The `^` and `$` can indeed be omitted as per @Thefourthbird.

Comment: I guess you are talking about `"*[your_pattern]*"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do ^ and $ mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908725/what-do-and-mean-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: How do I retrieve and extract the text after matching?

Comment: That would be a seperate question @HudZah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ^ asserts beginning of string. $ asserts end of string. Parenthesis are used to capture what's matched inside them. Both of these will work:

```
(\d{4}/\d{2}/\w/\w/\d{2})
^.*(\d{4}/\d{2}/\w/\w/\d{2}).*$
```

I'm not sure why you were escaping your backslashes. You may need to escape your forward slashes if forward slash is used as a delimiter in your program. I prefer to use ~ as delimiter as it is a rare character.

Comment: I get an error of Illegal escape character on android studio. Espacing the backslashes fixes the problem