# Using regex and its flags with .eq() function in python to ignore case

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I've checked the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

I'm thinking something like below where I can use and re.I to ingnore case or use any other flag for that matter.

```
df.column.eq('Male').sum()
```

Comment: Use `df.column.str.match()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html

Comment: You probably need `df['column'].str.contains('Male', case=False).sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Series.str.contains` function with `case=False` argument, `^Male$` as regex pattern and the `regex=True` argument:

```py
df['column'].str.contains('^Male$', case=False, regex=True).sum()
```

See the [`Series.str.contains` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Also, see [What do ^ and $ mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6908725/3832970)

Comment: So in df .contains, `regex=True` is the default, not necessary, that's what I was trying to find out, thanks for the documentation link

Answer (score 1):

Note that an alternative to setting case=False you can allow different case setting in words using a character set in the regex (ie. '^[Mm]ale$').

```
import pandas as pd
pupils = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
test_outcomes =['pass', 'fail', 'pass', 'fail', 'not passed', 'fail', 'fail', 'Pass']
test_results = pd.DataFrame(zip(pupils, test_outcomes), columns['pupil','outcome'])
passes = test_results[test_results['outcome'].str.contains('^[Pp]ass', regex=True)]
```

| pupil | outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pass |
| 3 | pass |
| 8 | Pass |